# How to tell on which node a local storage PV has been created on k8s?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-volume

I have provisioned manually a few small local storage PVs for a redis stateful set (I have provisioned 10 on a 3 node cluster)

They seem to to be working fine. The pods created by the redis stateful set got their volume claim templates fulfilled.

I am however curios, on which nodes each pv is hosted on

When I use `kubectl get pv`, I get the following output:

```
NAME             CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                          STORAGECLASS    REASON   AGE
small-volume-1   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Available                                    local-storage            51d
small-volume-2   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound         default/data-redis-cluster-3   local-storage            51d
small-volume-3   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Terminating   default/data-redis-cluster-1   local-storage            51d
small-volume-4   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound         default/data-redis-cluster-2   local-storage            51d
small-volume-5   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound         default/data-redis-cluster-5   local-storage            51d
small-volume-6   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Terminating   default/data-redis-cluster-0   local-storage            51d
small-volume-7   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Available                                    local-storage            51d
small-volume-8   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound         default/data-redis-cluster-4   local-storage            51d
small-volume-9   1Gi        RWO            Retain           Available                                    local-storage            51d
```

When I do `kubectl describe` on any of the PVs, I still don't see on which node it's on.

Is there a way to tell? (providing that I don't force them to be created on a specific node using node affinity)

Comment: According to https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/04/13/local-persistent-volumes-beta/ you have to set the node when you create the PV. 

Could you run `kubectl get pv --export=true -o yaml` that should dump the yaml config which will have...

`
nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
`
which tells you the node that volume is on.

Also when you run describe pv, do you get `Node Affinity:   <none>` ? I do but my PV's are not `local-storage`

Comment: Could you reply to the comment?